# Differentiation with respect to the index of the summation notion?

Tags: integration, derivatives, summation

$$\sum_{t=1}^k \binom{N-1}{t-1} \int[1-F(s)]^{N-1}[F(s)]^{t-1}g(s)\,ds$$

$k\in\mathbb Z ^+$

If I want to find out the effects of changing $k$ (comparative statics), what can I do? Differentiation will not work in this case, will it?

Comment: How would you like to interpret this? $k$ is discrete, and so you don't have well-defined derivatives against $k$. Or you might interpret the upper bound of the sum to be $\lfloor k \rfloor$, in which case the derivative is $0$ everywhere it's defined. Or perhaps you have a different interpretation?

Comment: thanks @mixedmath for your reply. I forgot the fact that k is discrete. Actually I am looking for a way to do comparative statics of how the function varies with k (normally by differentiating).

Comment: I suppose one analogue of the derivative in a discrete setting would be a difference, e.g., $f(k) - f(k-1)$, where $f(k)$ is the formula you gave.

Comment: I will try differencing. Thanks @PhillipAndreae